# How do I install pysvn into a virtualenv on W32?

Tags: python, svn, virtualenv, pysvn

On Windows platforms the psvn (python bindings for subversion) only comes as a w32 .exe installer.

Unfortunately I do not have the MS VC++ compiler, so the ideal solution would be to re-package the official release or convert an installation of PySVN into something that is redeployable.

I do have the MinGW complier, but unfortunately this does not seem to be supported on Windows.

Unlike many installers it does not seem to be possible to easy_install it, as it does not appear to behave like a a zip archive.

I want to install this package into the virtualenv, preferably without any manual steps. Is there a way to obtain pysvn as an egg, or convert the installer into an egg or some other format that is easy to deploy into the virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984096/456550) lists some ways to install binary packages in to a virtualenv.

To summarize, you can:

1. Activate the virtualenv and do `easy_install the_installer.exe`
2. Use the `add2virtualenv` command from [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
3. Symlink the install directory in to the virtualenv's site-packages.

These options do not work for pysvn on Windows. So far, the only way I have found to install it is globally. Then create the virtualenv with the `--system-site-packages` option.